# Bootstrap Navbar Hamburger Menu Not Working

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website with Bootstrap and when I use the following code for the navbar and reduce the dimensions of the display, the hamburger menu will not expand down and show the menu options:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Title</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menuItems" aria-controls="menuItems" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menuItems">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a target="_parent" class="nav-item nav-link active" href="index.html"> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The button is clickable but it's not showing the dropdown menu. Is it possible that someone can let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working in the snippet, make sure you have included Bootstrap's JavaScript file as well!

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Title</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#menuItems" aria-controls="menuItems" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menuItems">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"> <a target="_parent" class="nav-item nav-link active" href="index.html"> Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's Javascript controls the animations of Bootstrap components like the navbar or the carousel. Link the js files using the script tags. I would prefer not to use the minified versions (files with .min extension)